# Form under toolbar, can't get it down

Tags: vb6

[image]

The top of the form container is "up" under the toolbar. I can't find out how to get it down so that I can move the form to different areas on the screen. Using VB6.

Comment: After-thought...What put it up there in the first place?

Comment: you could move/hide that toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove -or rename- the (.vbw) file, that would reset window size & location.. Good luck :)

**Edit:**

You can also open the file with any text editor and change the form container position (in case you want to maintain the other settings

[image]

Comment: THAT did it, don't know why I never thought of that myself...DOH.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Click the form then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (hyphen) to open the MDI child forms default menu, hit <kbd>M</kbd> for the *Move* item and you can use the arrow keys (or mouse iirc) to move it around.